# Boot Ubuntu from a bootable USB hangs on purple screen

Tags: 13.04, dual-boot, syslinux

I recently bought a laptop (Lenovo Y410P) with Windows 8 pre-installed and I'm trying to dual boot Windows 8 and Ubuntu 13.0.

I created a bootable usb using Pendrive. Then I changed the Boot Mode to Legacy Support and the boot order so it boots from the flash storage first. When I restarted the computer, I got the error message 
"SYSLINUX 4.06 EDD 2012-10-23 Copyright (c) 1994-2012 H. Peter Anvin et al" 
and it just hung there.

Fair enough. After some googling I formatted my flash drive in FAT format instead of FAT32. The "SYSLINUX..." error message is gone but now it hangs on a purple screen

https://i.stack.imgur.com/QaGNj.jpg

Does anyone have a suggestion what to do here? I've looked at various posts but none of them seems to have a solution that the author confirmed it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the pen-drive doesn't support booting.
retry with another one.

Comment: Actually you are really of the mark. The one that should support booting in the system/BIOS/whatever. The pendrive is just a dumb storage.

Comment: No, that's not right i've tried it myself(on the same machine),one pendrive boots normally but my two other pendrives get my computer to hang during boot.

Comment: I bet you that the drive is damaged in some way or is not correctly setup. Try another machine or remake the USB stick bootable. Also, sticks that has persistent tools (like the U3) confuses some BIOS and won't boot or hangs up.

Comment: okay, you're the expert.

Comment: Even worse, it hangs on the UNetbootin option screen where you choose whether to try ubuntu or install it, etc.

Comment: i really think you should try with another pen-drive, just to make shoure.